# Grocerycrud search result

Tags: grocery-crud

I have two tables: cities and coutries.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` int(10) not null,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(1) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

My controller is:

```
public function cities() {

    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_theme('flexigrid');
    $crud->set_table('cities');
    $crud->where('active', 1);
    $crud->set_relation('country_id', 'countries', 'country');
    $output = $crud->render();
    $this->_example_output($output);
}

  public function countries() {

    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_theme('flexigrid');
    $crud->set_table('countries');
    $output = $crud->render();
    $this->_example_output($output);
}
```

If i try to search for the word "Tor" i would expect to see 1 rows but i will get all the rows! why?

my select is:

```
SELECT `cities`.*, j93bfec8a.country AS s93bfec8a
FROM `cities`
LEFT JOIN `countries` as `j93bfec8a` ON `j93bfec8a`.`id` = `cities`.`country_id`
WHERE `active` =0
OR  `j93bfec8a`.`country` LIKE '%Tor%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `city` LIKE '%Tor%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `active` LIKE '%Tor%' ESCAPE '!'
HAVING `active` =0
LIMIT 5
```

cities table:

```
id   country_id   city        active

1       2        Paris        1
2       2        Strasbourg   1
3       1        Torino       0
4       1        Milano       1
6       1        Rome         0
```

countries table:

```
   id   country

    1   Italy
    2   France
```

Someone to help me please!

I use grocerycrud v1.5.2 and codeigniter v3.0.3.

Comment: You are expecting 1 row, but I can't figure out if that's right or not. I have no idea what cities table looks like. Also not sure why you're defining an escape character.

Comment: sorry! result is in the pic: http://i67.tinypic.com/316tdo9.jpg

Comment: and grocerycrud generates sql with escape character.

Comment: Please edit your post to show the cities table. My firewall does not allow me to go to tinypic.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your query, this is the expected result.

It seems that the search pattern is added as and OR condition to the crud->where() filter. So, as you have

```
WHERE `active` = 0 OR ...
```

it will show ALL the records where this condition is true. I don't know if this is the intended GroceryCRUD behaviour.

In any case, maybe it would be better to use a [model](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_model)